# Hard Drive Recovery; Owned by 1001 and operations block

Tags: linux, hard-drive, data-recovery

I'm trying to recover data from a crashed hard drive. I have a SATA to USB cable and I'm trying to pull the data onto a temporary machine. The drive mounts just fine. However, the drive is owned by "1001:root". Trying to change the owner (or any read/write operation other than `ls` on directory containing the mount) result in a block, which can't be stopped with Ctrl+C; I had to `kill -9` it, after which the drive can't be unmounted since it's still busy from `chown`. Ordinary `cd` to the file failed until I `chmod`-ed the drive to 777, which caused the same blocking behavior as before. The drive's file system is (was) ext4. Any tips on how to maybe recover data, or is the whole thing borked?

Comment: Use backups....

Comment: Haha, we do have backups but we're short on drives and were hoping to save this one.